# Why does automatic type deduction fail?

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I have the following lines of code. I don't understand why template parameters need to be given (the highlighted part). Isn't the compiler able to deduce the type automatically? Since `myfunc` is defined already, I would think it is obvious which `Combiner` needs to be called.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
void Combiner(double a, std::function<void (T)> func){
  return func(std::to_string(a));
}

void myfunc(std::string a){
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return;
}


int main(){
  Combiner***<std::string>***(12, myfunc);
}
```

Comment: If you just want a quick fix change it to `void Combiner(double a, T func){`.  Still looking at the "why" part.

Comment: `myfunc` ≠ `std::function<void(std::string)>`.  Add this `std::function<void(std::string)> fn_myfunc = myfunc;` then `Combiner(12, fn_myfunc);`