# Why does automatic template deduction fail?

Tags: c++, templates

I've already asked a similar question here: [Why does automatic type deduction fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712346/why-does-automatic-type-deduction-fail)

However, I think I stripped down the code example too much in order to make a minimal working example. It does not reflect the problem I am facing.

Consider the code below. Why is it needed to add `<int, std::string>` as template arguments? Shouldn't the compiler be able to deduce this from `fn_myfunc` itself?

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>


template <class In, class Out>
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(
        std::function<Out (In)> process
    ) :
        process_(process)
    {
    }
private:
    std::function<Out (In)> process_;
};

std::string myfunc(int in) {
    return std::to_string(in);
}

int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
    std::function<std::string (int)> fn_myfunc = myfunc;
    MyClass<int, std::string> instance(fn_myfunc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you use C++17? Class template argument deduction is supported only since C++17.

Comment: C++17 [will deduce those arguments](https://godbolt.org/z/96c4bjMjj).  C++14 and earlier do not have [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).  The reason we have functions like `std::make_tuple` is because C++ could deduce function templates before it could deduce class templates.

Comment: see eg here: https://godbolt.org/z/KjxEKx778 No issue with C+17, if you cannot use C+17 you should mention in the question

Comment: btw if you have some code that fails you better show that code and also the resulting error message, then it is easier to help you. Currently we have to guess why it fails

Comment: Good point. The error I got is: `error: missing template arguments before ‘instance’`. It turns out I thought I was compiling with C++17, but I wasn't.